# Exception handling app/logs/dev.log

Tags: symfony

```
The stream or file "/home/nick/projects/Symfony/app/logs/dev.log" could not  
be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I get it in symfony.
I know that I can go to app/logs and delete dev.log but this is happening to often and is annoying to delete it again and againand again.

Is there any way to make it just disapear?

LE: I guess, that I got the reply.
I run the comands prefixed with `sudo`.

Eg: `sudo php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/StoreBundle` will work like a charm.

```
nick@ptb:~/projects/Symfony$ ls -al app/logs
total 76
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 nick     nick      4096 nov 24 15:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 nick     nick      4096 nov 24 15:28 ..
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 www-data www-data 59583 nov 24 16:25 dev.log
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 nick     nick         0 oct  6 15:55 .gitkeep
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that you create directory app/logs as sudo (root), so symfony doesn't have permissions to write into the file dev.log. Manually remove directory app/logs (and all contents), create it as normal user and setup up permissions, like they are described in the official documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html.

Something like:

```
$ sudo rm -rf app/logs
$ mkdir app/logs
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

Or use any other option which is described in official documentation.

If this not works then please paste us result of command:

```
$ ls -al app/logs
```

Comment: I just added the paste of `ls -al app/logs`. Thank you!

Comment: @crixi: that seems OK. Also check logs directory. It must have permissions drwxrwxr-x+

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I used CentOS 7 and I solved it by set **SELINUX=disabled** as follow.

```
 - sudo nano /etc/selinux/config
 - Edit the file by set SELINUX=disabled
 - Restart again then it worked !
```

I tested and tried many method included chmod, chwon, setfacl, etc but it cannot solve the problem until I tried above solution and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup.

**UPD**

Sometimes the solutions using ACL won't work, in this case try the forth option `4. Use the same user for the CLI and the web server`

Comment: This is correct, but it's not good practice to have all permissions 777.

Comment: You're right, it's the last thing to try though(only in development mode)

Comment: I already did those settings and I did them again right now. The problem is still there.

Comment: You tried the four options of `Setting up Permissions` explained in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup ? There is a dirty way to make it work (`chmod 777 -R app/cache chmod 777 -R app/logs`). As @rpincln said, it's not a good practice at all

Answer (score 0):

Use commands prefixed with sudo. I also got this error when I tried to run the server. Then I used 'sudo' and the error disappeared.

```
$ sudo php bin/console server:run
```